# How to make a function run before a button can be pressed again in JS?

Tags: javascript, button

I'm trying to write a program in JavaScript in which certain functions must be performed before a button can be pressed again.
The button performs a function that should only be performed once per turn, but I want other actions to be performed before the next turn, and to have a sort of confirmation before progressing to the next turn. In psuedocode it might look something like this:

```
buttonFunction();
actionOne();
actionTwo();
turnOverConfirm();
```

etc.

But I'm not so sure how to do that. Right now the button can be pressed at any time. How do I make it so that the user must confirm before the button can be pressed again?

Comment: You can try hiding the button and showing the button at times you want user to interact with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable and enable buttons via javascript. You could block it like that:
`document.getElementById("button").disabled = true`

Just set it to false again to make it clickable again!

Comment: That seems to make the most sense considering how the program flows. The button performs a function when it is clicked so it seems easy enough to add that on to the end of that function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript confirm function. This function will popup a message box with `ok` and `cancel`

Here is an example

```
var r = confirm("Press a button!");
if (r == true) {
    alert("OK was clicked");
} else {
    alert("Cancel was clicked");
}
```

What you can do is when a user clicks on a button, popup a confirm box, then if they click ok you can then run the function you listed above.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways

- You can hide the button till processing is ready or replace with an "please wait..." image
- You can create an prevent varaible or remove temporary click event function

```
var Action = (function(){
var prevent = false;
    function _start() {
    if (prevent === false) {
    prevent = true;
    _process();
    }
    }
    function _process() {
    // DO Action
    prevent = false;
    }
    return { start: _start }
    })();

    <a href="javascript:Action.start()">Fire</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make event for evry click here is an example with alert and change button color all in one function

```js
var clicked = 0;
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

function clickBtn(){
    if (clicked == 0) {
      alert("it's first click");
      btn.style.background = "black";
      clicked = 1;
    }else if (clicked == 1) {
        alert("it's second click");
        btn.style.background = "orange";
        clicked = 2;
      } else if (clicked == 2) {
          alert("it's third click");
          btn.style.background = "green";
          clicked = 3;
        } 
    }
```

```css
#btn{
border-radius:15px 0 15px 0;
color:white;
border:none;
padding:15px;
background:blue;
font-weight:bold;
}

#btn:hover{
border-radius:0 15px 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="clickBtn()">Click Me</button>
```